# Set cell link at run time for Forms Check Box

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on pulling data out of a standardized form in excel.  There is a Forms Control CheckBox that I need the state of.  Apparently the only way to get this is from the cell link, where the value is placed into a cell.  The problem is, whomever put this form together did not set a cell link.  Is there any way to do this using VBA at run time.  There are many of these forms that I must go through, so I'm trying to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: What's wrong with `frmTest.Checkbox1.Value` ?  Unless this control is on a worksheet, in which case do you know the name of the checkbox?  +1 Reafidy - take a few minutes to review your past questions and accept some answers (or else maybe explain why they didn't work for you)

Comment: Tim, the control is on a worksheet.  The name of the checkbox is "Check Box 1".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a forms checkbox control placed on a worksheet, in which case you can get the state of the control without setting a cell link.  Like this:

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim iLoop As Integer       

    '// Get value of check box by its index
    MsgBox (GetCheckBoxState(1))

    '// Get value of check box by its name
    MsgBox (GetCheckBoxState("Check Box 1"))

     '// Loop through all checkboxes and get values
    For iLoop = 1 To ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count
        MsgBox (GetCheckBoxState(iLoop))
    Next

End Sub
Function GetCheckBoxState(vCheckBox As Variant) As String
    Select Case ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(vCheckBox).Value
        Case xlOn
            GetCheckBoxState = "Checked"
        Case xlOff
          GetCheckBoxState = "UnChecked"
        Case xlMixed
          GetCheckBoxState = "Mixed"
    End Select
End Function
```

If you are referring to a check box control on a userform then as Tim pointed out it should be a case of something like:

```
MsgBox (UserForm1.CheckBox1.Value)
```

Comment: This didn't do the trick.  The Select Case throws an application defined or object defined error.  In the debugger, the value of vCheckBox is -4146 regardless of whether or not the box is checked.

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: It looks like the checkbox used was supposed to be linked to a cell to hold its value.  This never happened, so I don't know if anything can be done.  This has been put on the back-burner for now, but I will need some sort of solution at some point.

Comment: Try giving us some feedback, did the code work, if not what was the error or why didn't it work.  Do you still want a vba solution? etc...  Help us help you. :)

Comment: This situation appears to be more about whomever put the form together doing a poor job of setting it up correctly.  As of right now, I am not looking for a VBA solution.  Thanks for all of your help, though.

Comment: No worries at all.  Fixing someone else's mess ups is always fun!